argsub,subs, simplify in maple
I have this line of codes in maple
and not giving the the expression even after in use eval an evalm
v := Vector[column]([
    (sigma[h] + mu[h])*E[h],
    -1 + kappa*sigma[h]*E[h] + (omega[h] + mu[h])*A[h],
    -kappa*sigma[h]*E[h] + ((xi/(1 + gamma*I[h])) + sigma[1] + mu[h])*I[h],
    -xi*I[h]/(1 + gamma*I[h]) + (sigma[2] + mu[h] + alpha[h])*T[h],
    (sigma[r] + mu[r])*E[r],
    -sigma[r]*E[r] + mu[r]*I[r]
]);
V=jacobian(v,[E[h],A[h],I[h],T[h],E[r],I[r]]);
now i want to replace this value in the matrix with K
-xi/(gamma*I[h] + 1) + (xi*gamma*I[h])/(gamma*I[h] + 1)^2 = K
with this code
VV:=subs(expr=m,V);
but the output is giving
VV=V 

please i need correction nin this codeyour text
simplify gives the same thing and argsubs bring error
Error, (in algsubs) cannot compute degree of pattern in gamma

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

restart;

# `I` is the default imaginary unit, so
# set that to another name if you want to
# use names like I[r], I[h], etc.
# (Or, use different names for those...)
interface(imaginaryunit=j):

v := Vector[column]([
    (sigma[h] + mu[h])*E[h],
    -1 + kappa*sigma[h]*E[h] + (omega[h] + mu[h])*A[h],
    -kappa*sigma[h]*E[h] + ((xi/(1 + gamma*I[h])) + sigma[1] + mu[h])*I[h],
    -xi*I[h]/(1 + gamma*I[h]) + (sigma[2] + mu[h] + alpha[h])*T[h],
    (sigma[r] + mu[r])*E[r],
    -sigma[r]*E[r] + mu[r]*I[r]
]);

# You forgot to actually assign the
# following to `v`. You used just `=`
# instead of `:=`
# Also, linalg[jacobian] is deprecated since
# about 20 years ago, and produces the also
# deprecated `vector` instead of `Vector`.
V := VectorCalculus:-Jacobian(v,[E[h],A[h],I[h],T[h],E[r],I[r]]);

expr := -xi/(gamma*I[h] + 1) +
 (xi*gamma*I[h])/(gamma*I[h] + 1)^2;

# `subs` will not suffice in all elements,
# since in some of them the terms above
# appear only as *part* of a larger sum
# of terms.
# So, instead, use simplify with side-relations
simplify(V,{expr=K});

